# Java unicode byte parsing

Tags: java, string, unicode, encoding

I'm just in the process of reading some data from a file as a stream of bytes, and I've just encountered some unicode strings that I'm not sure how best to handle.

Each character is using two bytes, with only the first seeming to contain actual data, so for example the string 'trust' is stored in the file as:

```
0x74 0x00(t) 0x72 0x00(r) ...and so on
```

Normally I'd just use a regex to replace the zeros with nothing and therefore remove the whitespace.  However, the spaces between words within the file are implemented using `0x00 0x00`, so trying to do a simple String 'replaceAll' is kind of messing it up a little.

I've tried playing around with the String encoding sets, such as 'ISO-8859-1' and 'UTF-8/16', but everytime I end up with white space.

I did create a simple regex to remove the double zero hex values, which is:

```
new String(bytes).replaceAll("[\\00]{2,},"");
```

But this obviously only works for the double zero, and I'd really like to replace single zeros with nothing, and double zeros with a an actual ASCII/Unicode space character.

I could have sworn that one of the Java string format settings dealt with this kind of thing, but I might be wrong.  So should I work on creating a regex to strip out the zeros, or does Java actually provide the mechanisms for doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's `"UTF-16LE"`. `0x00 0x00` actually encodes the NUL character in UTF-16 so that's what you will get.

This encoding can encode about a million different characters, using 2 or 4 bytes per character. The first 256 characters are encoded with the second byte `0x00` and if the text only contains those it could be seen as useless, but it's required for the rest of the characters. For instance, the euro currency symbol `€` would show up as `0xAC 0x20`.

Comment: Ahh yes, so it is, I couldn't find that for looking.  That's answered my question and fixed it.  Thanks very much for the quick reply, I'll click accepted as soon as I can.  Thanks Esailija!

Answer (score 5):

> I'm just in the process of reading some data from a file as a stream of bytes, and I've just encountered some unicode strings that I'm not sure how best to handle.

Convert them to strings using the appropriate charset, in this case UTF-16LE (little-endian UTF-16, with the low-order byte first followed by the high-order byte)

```
String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, that's exactly what I've done.  Out of interest, what's the best way of identifying the type of unicode  charset being used?

Comment: @Tony generally encodings are not identified but explicitly told. Like if you got the file from a http server, the server probably sent you a http header containing the encoding. Without this information, automatic detection of encoding is not reliable. Manually one can do a best guess and see if the text comes out correctly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection

Comment: @Tony there isn't really a "best way" unless the data starts with a byte order mark - if the first two bytes are FE FF then it's big-endian UTF-16, FF FE then it's little-endian UTF-16, EF BB BF it's UTF-8.  But if you're reading a binary format then the format specification ought to tell you what encoding (including endianness) to expect.