# java client and C# server working with unicode

Tags: java, c#, android, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to build a tcp client and a server that will work with unicode. the server is in `C#` and looks like that:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // tcp setup
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();

        // waiting for client to connect
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

        // client comunication
        string resAscii = Recv(clientSocket);
        Send(clientSocket, "got from you: " + resAscii);
        string resUnicode = Recv(clientSocket);
        Send(clientSocket, "קיבלתי ממך: " + resUnicode);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Send(TcpClient client, string msg)
    {
        Byte[] sendtBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(msg + "$");
        client.GetStream().Write(sendtBytes, 0, sendtBytes.Length);
        client.GetStream().Flush();
    }
    public static string Recv(TcpClient client)
    {
        byte[] recvBytes = new byte[65537];
        client.GetStream().Read(recvBytes, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recvBytes);
        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf('$'));
        return dataFromClient;
    }
```

and the client is in `java` (android):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.102", 8888);
                Send(s, "this is ascii");
                String asciiString = Recv(s);
                Send(s, "זה יוניקוד");
                String unicodeString = Recv(s);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}


private String Recv(Socket s) throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[10080];
    int read = s.getInputStream().read(b, 0, 1000);
    String ret = new String(b, "UTF16");
    ret = ret.substring(0, ret.indexOf('$'));
    return ret;
}

private void Send(Socket s, String msg) throws IOException {
    s.getOutputStream().write((msg + "$").getBytes("UTF16"));
}
```

When I'm sending from the client to the server I get the message. But when the server sending to the client I get only Chinese letters:
[client (android) error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0S6A.png)
how can I fix it?

Comment: try `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175545/encoding-unicode-getbytes-c-sharp-to-java

Comment: "this is ascii": saying it doesn't make it so; It's UTF-16 because that's what a string is.

Comment: @flakes If you where next to me I would kiss you...

Comment: @roni lol glad it worked out :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java unicode byte parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749966/java-unicode-byte-parsing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @flakes said that was the answer.
change this line in the `Recv` function:

```
    String ret = new String(b, "UTF16");
```

with this line:

```
        String ret = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```

and

```
    s.getOutputStream().write((msg + "$").getBytes("UTF16"));
```

with this line in the `Send` file:

```
        s.getOutputStream().write((msg + "$").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
```

Comment: This is because [When decoding, the UTF-16 charset interprets the byte-order mark at the beginning of the input stream to indicate the byte-order of the stream but defaults to big-endian if there is no byte-order mark; when encoding, it uses big-endian byte order and writes a big-endian byte-order mark.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)